# Host ghost on github: buster generate... failed: Connection refused

Tags: github, ghost-blog, buster.js

I'm trying to host ghost on github page. I can see my ghost blog on my Mac. But, when I run:

```
buster generate --domain=http://localhost:2368
```

The connection is error. The display like this:

[image: Screen capture: failed: Connection refused.]

The display in terminal like this:

```
--2018-07-05 11:07:26--  http://localhost:2368/
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:2368... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost|::1|:2368... failed: Connection refused.
Converted links in 0 files in 0 seconds.
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a static site using ghost then check out [ember-ghost](http://github.com/stonecircle/ember-ghost)

**Ember Ghost**

> A fully-functional, SEO friendly static site implementation of a blog system built on Ember.
>
> It currently has 2 ghost themes [Casper](https://github.com/stonecircle/ember-ghost-casper-template), [Attila](https://github.com/stonecircle/ember-ghost-attila-template) which have been ported to work with ember-ghost. You can also create your own ember-ghost theme if you want.
>
> Write your blog using Markdown

Answer (score 0):

You have to start ghost in **localhost** and use buster tool to convert the pages. Buster then stores the files in a folder called **static**

try

```
ghost start
```

and find which port ghost is running on with the command

```
ghost status
```

browse to

```
http://localhost:2368
```

replace the port number if it is different

then use buster

```
sudo buster generate --domain=http://localhost:2368
sudo buster deploy
```

Check out my [repo](https://github.com/abhijithvijayan/ghost-on-github-pages) of my blog on github pages for any help.